# Is there a recommended way to test if a smart pointer is null?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I'm trying to check if a `std::shared_ptr` is null. Is there a difference between doing

```
std::shared_ptr<int> p;
if (!p) { // method 1 }
if (p == nullptr) { // method 2 }
```

Comment: No difference at all. You could also write if(not p.get())

Comment: What about `if (p.get() == nullptr)`?

Comment: No difference. One is a lot less typing.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> Is there a difference between doing
>
> ```
>  std::shared_ptr<int> p;
>  if (!p) { // method 1 }
>  if (p == nullptr) { // method 2 }
> ```

No, there's no difference. Either of that operations has a [properly defined overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_cmp).

Another equivalent would be

```
 if(p.get() == nullptr)
```

Comment: In theory the 3rd one could be more complex in relatively insane situations, as it must get the `T*` prior to comparing to nullptr.  Imagine a type erased smart pointer that must call a vtable method prior to getting the `T*`, but if the value is null guarantees a nullptr vtable.  Method 1 and 2 can short circuit the possible extract-`T*`, while 3 could not, because `.get()` does not know it will be just checked for null.

Answer (score 0):

`shared_ptr` provides a specific operator for bool conversion [`std::shared_ptr::operator bool`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/operator%20bool/).

Test if not set:

```
if (!p)
```

Test if set:

```
if (p)
```

You can be very explicit about your intent with:

```
if (static_cast<bool>(p))
```

Comment: I do not agree with your intent being explicit in your example. The intent is to check for `nullptr`, so `p != nullptr` **is** more explicit for the question. In your example you are only explicit about your intent to invoke `operator bool`.

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik The intent is about knowing if the shared_ptr has been set/reset